# foreground & background separation from image using python and opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

here I'm doing Soil Height measurement Project using Python & Opencv
i am trying to calculate height from fixed bottom line to upper boundary of soil mountains shown in image.

for that purpose i wanted to do **foreground & background separation**. i tried a lot but didn't work as we want general logic to do that

from the above image i only wanted a Soil Mountains so i can calculate distance
& wanted to remove background

[image: test image]
error in image not taking top edge of moutain
[error in image not taking top edge of moutain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJu7v.png)
[image: end goal is to cal distance]

```
""" 
     Our operations on the frame come here
    """
    frame = img_op.resize_img(frame, (512, 512))
    gray = img_op.get_grayscale(frame)

    # if i put this it's removing all edges
    # i wanted only top edges of the soil
    blurred = img_op.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5))  
  
    mean_of_frame = np.mean(blurred)
    min_threshold = 0.66 * mean_of_frame
    max_threshold = 1.33 * mean_of_frame
    print(f"mean: {mean_of_frame} min_th: {min_threshold} max_th: {max_threshold}")
    # Canny = img_op.canny(blurred, 30, 150)

    Canny = img_op.canny(blurred, min_threshold, max_threshold)


    ## To make green, red color to white
    x = get_HSV_process_frame(frame)
    Canny[x] = 255

    no_zero_cnts_x1_y1_th_val = 80
    vertical_col = Canny[:, col_no]
    # print(list(enumerate(vertical_col)))

    """ Get the Cordinates """
    try:
        x1, y1 = get_x1_y1_cordinate(vertical_col, col_no, no_zero_cnts_x1_y1_th_val)
    except Exception as e:
        x1, y1 = col_no, 438
        print("X1, Y1 Problem", e)
        blurr_flag = True

    # bottom cordinates are fix
    x2, y2 = (col_no, 438)
```

Logic for getting x1 & y1 is
i am searching for white pixel from top once i got white pixel i'm counting black pixel if i got **continuous** 80 black pixel after white pixel. i'm considering that white pixel as a x1, y1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SK4fG.jpg)

Comment: *"I tried a lot"*, please share what you have tried

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i added a info if you want more plz let me know @JeruLuke

Comment: @satyam Since you are using HSV color space, you can try converting to LAB color space and analyze the individual channels

Comment: i have used color space for to make trees and red color to white bt it didn't work.
my main problem is foreground & background separation.
i only wanted a Soil Mountains so i can calculate distance & wanted to remove background (i tried by Adaptive threshholding bt didn't work)

test image

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion here is to look at deltas. Between the stair and the background is clear horizontal (ish) break. A transformation to get the light, or hue delta's between pixels (or groups of) in a horizontal direction may find the boundary between that stair and the soil. Cut here to exclude other noise?

A similar trick could be used on the vertical, however, the soil wall to floor transition is subtle, more so than some of the transitions within the soil - so this could only get you part of the way.